# Hasse diagram for poset including pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, order-theory

I created a Hasse diagram for the poset $(\Box_4^2, \leq)$ with $\Box_4 = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $\leq$ being defined as

$$(a,b) \leq (c,d)
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
(a<c \text{ and } b<d)
\;\text{ or }\;
(a=c \text{ and } b=d).$$

So the relation $\leq$ takes in $2$ pairs of numbers. Two pairs are in a relation if they're equal to each other or if both elements of the pair are smaller than the elements of the other pair.

The diagram looks like:
[Hasse diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7lNp.png)

Some elements have a relation with an element that is more than one level above them however, and I'm thinking this diagram might be faulty.

Edit: I have constructed a [new diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6n8v.png). I believe this poset does not have a least upper bound nor a greatest lower bound, is this correct?

Comment: That diagram is a mess! You can improve it by starting with the chains (in this order, left to right): $$\{(3,0)\},$$
$$\{(2,0)<(3,1)\},$$ 
$$\{(1,0)<(2,1)<(3,2)\},$$ 
$$\{(0,0)<(1,1)<(2,2)<(3,3)\},$$
$$\{0,1<(1,2)<(2,3)\},$$
$$\{(0,2)<(1,3)\},$$
$$\{(0,3)\}.$$
Then, add the lines corresponding to coverings between elements of different chains. For example, $(2,0)<(3,2)$, $(1,0)<(3,1)$, etc. You will find that the diagram is symmetric (left to right) and easy to read (yours is wrong, at least it misses some connections).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. My [new diagram](https://imgur.com/a/erjC47n) looks a lot cleaner. Is it correct that this poset does not have a least upper bound, nor a greatest lower bound?

Comment: I think you' got it right, now! I would suggest you to answer your own question posting that diagram (not a link to it, but the picture itself). Later on (I think after 24 hours), you'll have the chance to accept your answer. It is cleat that this poset has neither a least nor a greatest element, and there are many pairs for which there is neither a greatest lower bound nor a least upper bound.

Comment: I also edited your post to typeset the mathematical content using MathJax. Fell free to roll back that edit if you don't like it.